Electric hot water tank controls often needs reset
After hurricane Milton one of my tenants didn't have hot water.  I found the heating elements burned out. ( I assumed that they turned on the power to the tank before turning on the water and they ran while dry) I replaced them.
They had hot water for a day. Then called and no hot water again. This time I replaced the thermostat. ( It had needed reset, but I replaced it since I had one onhand.)
Good hot water for a week. Now they are saying they have to push the reset on the thermostat every time one of them takes a shower or they do laundry.
Before replacing the heating elements I checked all connections and checked the draw ( only 14 amps)  What could be the issue? The tank is only 28 month old. The water is very good without many minerals. It's a 40 gal tank serving only 2 people.
Please note:  This is an issue of the thermostat needing the red reset button pressed often, ( 2 to 3 times a day.) not an issue of the water just not being hot enough for them. It's set to 125.
(This is not an apartment building or a commercial space. Just one home I rent out)

Did any outside(flood) water get to the tank?  Do not know about newer tanks, but they do seem to like to fill stuff up with electronics that are not really needed(power surge).

No, there was no flooding in the area  The tank sits on a pedestal about 20 inches above the floor.

Hot water hysteria? Could they just be more sensitive to normal variations in hot water temperature now? If there's no LED or other indicator that shows "reset required" and they're convinced that the water is not hot enough - though nothing is wrong - and pushing reset (or not) eventually restores hot water to their feel-good temperature? You could temporarily wire a neon test light across the heating element. If it's on, no reset is required, the water is heating and time is all that's required.

@MTA, this is a good thought.  They have been good tenants for over 2 years and never had a complaint.  I trust that when they say no hot water it really isn't hot, but that may not be the case.  I guess I need to examine the temp. myself.

does the capacity of the thermostat match the heating element?

Was the temperature setting of the new thermostat the same as the old one?

Elements and thermostat were purchased as a set.  The temp was set 5 degrees higher on the new tstadt.

Any chance you got a bum tstat/reset?  Maybe someone returned a bad one to your home store and you bought it?  Those resets trip at around 180 degree F.  That's pretty hot water to then say no hot water.

@Jack,  I purchased a "Kit that was factory sealed. The tstadt and 2 elements and the lower tstadt.  ( I am careful to not buy opened packages)  I think what is happening is the tstadt is opening the breaker and then as they use water they realize it is not hot.  This is some weird electrical issue.  I may buy another tstadt and see if that works.
